# Magento SUPEE6788 how to make my extension compatible with magento older version

Tags: magento-1.8, security

After installing Magento SUPEE6788 patches my module stop working so as per the instruction provided by magento in  http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details and change config.xml

```
<admin>
   <routers>
      <adminhtml> 
         <args>
            <modules> 
               <Module_Name after="Mage_Adminhtml">ModuleName_Adminhtml</Module_Name>
            </modules> 
          </args> 
      </adminhtml>
   </routers>
</admin>
```

it is working with it but I want to make it compatible with magento 1.9.1 and lower how to perform it can anyone had any idea to perform it

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly this way of defining adminhtml routers is already since Magento 1.6 or so. If you want to make it compatible with Magento versions before that it's probably easier to make a second version of your module

Comment: there is slight change in
 <args>
                    <modules> 
                    <Module_Name after="Mage_Adminhtml">ModuleName_Adminhtml</Module_Name>
                    </modules> 
                </args>

Comment: That is due to the patch but if older stores are patched they should have it as well. Trying to make it compatible with unpatched stores is something I wouldn't recommend